# Enter Key button with Dialog box

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dialog box with an ok button, the ok button works, but i want the user to be able to press enter on the keyboard as well, this is the code i have, any suggestions?

```
function showDialog()
{
    $('#dialog').dialog('destroy');
    $('#dialog').show();
    $('#dialog').html();

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 120,
        width: 370,
        overlay: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            opacity: 0.9
        },
        title:"Enter possible answer"
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.onkeypress=function(e){
if(e.keyCode==13)
{
showDialog();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dialog").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        // your code
        showDialog();
    }
});
})
```

Comment: I think this is the better approach, since the OP mentions it being done from a dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to catch the keypress event:

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    //code
}
```

That JS will check whether or not the enter key was pressed, this code will work on all browsers/platforms.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dialog').onKeyDown(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    // just trigger the submit handler
alert('Enter');
  }
```